# MongoDB: How to find the exact version of installed MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have mongoDB 3.2 installed locally for Windows 7. I would like to find out its specific version (like is it 3.2.1, or 3.2.3 or...). How could I find it? If I open the database shell (mongo.exe), I can see it outputs:

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0

But that's just the shell version, and I'm not sure whether it's the same as my real database version.

Comment: had the same question and `db.version()` gives me the same version as the shell version, but still wondering if this is always the case, or just coincidence in my case.

Also, when I run `/usr/bin/mongo --version`, I get `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12`, so this still refers to the "mongodb shell"

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Just run your console and type:

```
db.version()
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.version/

Answer (score 174):

## Option1:

Start the console and execute this:

```
db.version()
```

## Option2:

Open a shell console and do:

> $ mongod --version

It will show you something like

> $ mongod --version
>   db version v3.0.2

Answer (score 21):

To check MongoDB version use the mongod command with `--version` option.

To check the MongoDB Server version, Open the command line via your terminal program and execute the following command:

Path:
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`
Open Cmd and
execute the following command:
`mongod --version`
To Check MongoDB Shell version:
`mongo --version`

Answer (score 9):

**mongo --version**

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
```

**mongod --version**

```
db version v2.6.10
```

**mongo**

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: test
```

**db.version()**

```
2.6.10
```

Answer (score 4):

From the Java API:

```
Document result = mongoDatabase.runCommand(new Document("buildInfo", 1));
String version = (String) result.get("version");
List<Integer> versionArray = (List<Integer>) result.get("versionArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to see **version of mongodb** after making a connection from your **project/application/code**. In this case you can follow like this:

```
 mongoose.connect(
    encodeURI(DB_URL), {
      keepAlive: true
    },
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }else{
           const con = new mongoose.mongo.Admin(mongoose.connection.db)
              con.buildInfo( (err, db) => {
              if(err){
                throw err
              }
             // see the db version
             console.log(db.version)
            })
      }
    }
  )
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.exe" --version

just run in cmd adjust it your path

Answer (score -3):

For Mac users try running this command

```sh
brew services start mongodb-community
```