# ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 4

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to run this command

```
#mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
```

but I got this message

> about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
>   forked process: 10750
>   all output going to: /var/log/mongod.log
>   log file [/var/log/mongod.log] exists; copied to temporary file
>   [/var/log/mongod.log.2017-05-23T14-57-31]
>   ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 4

Could you please help me resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/):

> 4
>      The version of the database is different from the version supported by the mongod (or mongod.exe) instance. The instance exits cleanly.

Comment: Did you try to [find out the version of your db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160412/how-to-find-the-exact-version-of-installed-mongodb) by db.version() ? If it is different from what your mongod.exe supports, you have to [upgrade it](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/), (see 'Follow this upgrade procedure:...').

Comment: my mongodb version is 
db version v2.4.9

Comment: Great! Do you have a standalone, a replica set, or sharded cluster? Did you try to [upgrade your database accordingly](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-standalone/)?